# Is there a way to get sorted PSCustomObjects after using Compare-Object on two .JSON files?

Tags: powershell, sorting, pscustomobject

I am comparing .JSON files, using `Compare-Object` like this:

```
# Compare two files 
$BLF = (Get-Content -Path C:\Users\...\Documents\Android1.json)
$CLF = (Get-Content -Path C:\Users\...\Documents\Android2.json)

$a = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $BLF -DifferenceObject $CLF -IncludeEqual
```

Then `$a` is a `System.Array`. It contains all the lines in the .JSON files each in an `InputObject`, and `SideIndicator` to show the difference. Thus for a difference such as

```
# From file 1  
"workProfilePasswordMinimumLength":  false,
"workProfilePasswordMinLowerCaseCharacters":  false,
"workProfilePasswordMinUpperCaseCharacters":  null,
"deviceManagementApplicabilityRuleOsEdition":  null,

# From file 2 
"workProfilePasswordMinimumLength":  true,
"workProfilePasswordMinLowerCaseCharacters":  false,
"workProfilePasswordMinUpperCaseCharacters":  null,
"deviceManagementApplicabilityRuleOsEdition":  true,
```

the compare function gives using

```
$a.psobject.ImmediateBaseObject
```

the output:

```
InputObject                                              SideIndicator
-----------                                              -------------
    "workProfilePasswordMinLowerCaseCharacters":  false, ==           
    "workProfilePasswordMinUpperCaseCharacters":  null,  ==           
    "workProfilePasswordMinimumLength":  true,              =>           
    "deviceManagementApplicabilityRuleOsEdition":  true, =>           
    "workProfilePasswordMinimumLength":  false,             <=           
    "deviceManagementApplicabilityRuleOsEdition":  null, <=
```

My probem is: I want to sort these InputObjects so that they are like this:

```
InputObject                                              SideIndicator
-----------                                              -------------
    "workProfilePasswordMinLowerCaseCharacters":  false, ==           
    "workProfilePasswordMinUpperCaseCharacters":  null,  ==           
    "workProfilePasswordMinimumLength":  true,              =>           
    "workProfilePasswordMinimumLength":  false,             <=     
    "deviceManagementApplicabilityRuleOsEdition":  true, =>     
    "deviceManagementApplicabilityRuleOsEdition":  null, <=
```

So that the matching names, when the variables are different, are sorted. How can I sort them?

Comment: The easiest solution often works like a charm: `Sort-Object`

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe the output of the `Compare-Object` cmdlet to [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-7) like so

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $BLF -DifferenceObject $CLF -IncludeEqual |
    Sort-Object -Property InputObject
```

Since it sorts the output by InputProperty, you get

```
InputObject                                         SideIndicator   
-----------                                         -------------   
"deviceManagementApplicabilityRuleOsEdition":  null <=
"deviceManagementApplicabilityRuleOsEdition":  true =>
"workProfilePasswordMinimumLength":  false          <=
"workProfilePasswordMinimumLength":  true           =>
"workProfilePasswordMinLowerCaseCharacters":  false ==
"workProfilePasswordMinUpperCaseCharacters":  null  ==
```

This is slightly different from the output you posted. If you need the output exactly as you posted, then you can use a custom sorting expression.

`Sort-Object -Property @{Expression={ <some expression> }}`